# Communicate between a macOS app and a C++ app that is running on a virtual windows environment on the same machine

Tags: c++, windows, macos, sockets, virtual-machine

I'm trying to rig together a complicated setup and it deals with various realms of coding that I don't know enough about, so I'm hoping for some advice/brainstorming help from the community.

Here's the setup:

There is a C++ library which I need to use, but it only works on windows. Let's say that this library has a function called `foo` which takes a single argument that is a number. I want to create a small C++ program which parses custom strings and interprets them as commands to be sent to the library. For example, if the small C++ program receives the string `foo 4.3` it will invoke `foo(4.3)` in the library because it knows the function names and argument lists that it is expecting. To be clear, I will write the parsing code in C++ - I don't need the incoming string to be automatically translated into a call into the library, I'll do it manually.

The real tricky part is that I want to setup a virtual windows machine on my MacBook and run this small C++ program on it, and then somehow send these custom strings (e.g., `foo 4.3`) across the boundary from a SwiftUI mac app that I write into the virtual machine windows environment to be picked up by the small C++ program, which then invokes the appropriate library function, and then sends the response (if any) back across the boundary in a similar customized string format to my SwiftUI mac app. I don't know much about sockets, but a friend who I spoke with suggested that it may be possible to send strings back and forth between the mac and the virtual windows machine using sockets.

My specific question is, is it possible to send and receive strings from a macOS app to a windows environment running on a virtual machine on the same device and if so, is sockets the way to go or is there some other technology I need to use?

Comment: Network socket should do the job and be relatively simple. If you go with a TCP socket, remember that TCP is a stream, so you'll have to build in your own protocol to let the receiver know when a message ends. Because it's message oriented and the odds of packet loss are very low when a computer talks to itself, you may want to look into using UDP.

Comment: Look at [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers), and [gRPC](https://grpc.io/).